# Adding children gameOjects to array?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am adding children gameObjects to an array. This below script is attached to parent gameObject. I get all the children objects into the array but unfortunately even the parent gets added to the array. How do I remove the parent from the array?

```
public Transform[] children;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
   children= GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    foreach (Transform i in children)
    {
       ...
    }
```

Comment: Why not use transform.childcount and transform.getchild(x) where x is the counter and basically already is your array of children

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You usually don't need this!

Rather if you only want direct (first level) children simply iterate the parent `Transform`

```
var childrenList = new List<Trasnform>();
foreach(Transform child in transform)
{
    // This iterates over all direct children, not the parent

    childrenList.Add(child);
}

Transform[] children = childrenList.ToArray();
```

---

Or yes if you need also nested children you can use

```
using System.Linq;

...

Transform[] children = GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>(true).Where(child => child != transform).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its not the efficent way to achieve this but you can try this approach,

```
var transforms = GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
foreach(var transform in transforms)
{
   //ignore parent
    if(transform == this.transform)
        continue;

}
```